# Remove everything above a given node in a recursive data structure

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have a datastructure of the form

```
node: { "name": "root";
        "children": [ node ]; }
```

there is another example at the bottom of the question.

Now I would like to remove all nodes above a specified one and only keep the remaining sub-tree.

So for example, given the tree T

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

the function `getTree(T, 'C')` should return

```
   C
  / \
 D   E
```

Question: is there an easy way to implement this?

```
function getTree(json, node) {
    var tree = JSON.parse(json);
    /* QUESTION: how do I remove everything not below the node with name===node here?
}
```

---

PS: larger example:

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];
```

---

Edit: good point: I should have mentioned that the node names are unique.

Comment: Does the tree have any ordering guarantees? If there are multiple nodes with the same label, which one should be returned? Topmost? Leftmost?

Comment: @amon i have edited the post: the node names are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the array and look if the node has the wanted text or if the nested nodes have a found.

```js
const
    getTree = (tree, text) => {
        let result;
        tree.some(node => result = node.text === text
            ? node
            : getTree(node.nodes || [], text)
        );
        return result;
    },
    tree = [{ text: "Parent 1", nodes: [{ text: "Child 1", nodes: [{ text: "Grandchild 1" }, { text: "Grandchild 2" }] }, { text: "Child 2" }] }, { text: "Parent 2" }, { text: "Parent 3" }, { text: "Parent 4" }, { text: "Parent 5" }];

console.log(getTree(tree, "Grandchild 1"));
console.log(getTree(tree, "Parent 1"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```